# how can achieve copy /move list data to another site list for behalf of individual user

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

how can achieve  copy /move list data to another site list for  behalf of individual  user .
Scenario  is:-
In A site collection two department site one is IT And 2nd Student services. A emp in two year work in IT And now last one year Working in Student services deparment . A emp Fill daily activity sheet in Both Department . so now A emp want to all data show in Student services sheet means Both Department list Data, how can achieve,please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Datasheet view of the list.
2. Filter the data based on required user.
3. Copy all the Data from Source list.
4. Paste it in the datasheet view of Destination list.
5. Delete the data from source list if it is no more needed.

I think this is the most simple way to move the data from one list to another. If you want to do it in a expensive way, you may go for migration tool such as AvePoint DocAve, Metalogix, etc.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a SharePoint designer workflow to copy all data from existing list to other list
- Write a timer job which checks the created date against each item and based on timeline defined it's archive the data in other list
- Also if this is a one time activity you can write power shell script to move data from one list to other
- Another option is to try this [migration solution](http://www.lepide.com/lepidemigratordocuments/sharepoint-to-office-365-migration.html) to move the data from one list to another easily and efficiently.

You should be able to use Site Content and Structure to move your items: `<siteurl> /_layouts/sitemanager.aspx`

Go to your source list, select the items you want to move (you can do select all from the checkbox at the top left) the click the Actions menu and click "Move..."

It may not move some fields like created, modified etc but most metadata and attachments should work.

Hope that's helps you.